# criptografia mão dupla com LENGTH fixo

Tags: php, compressão

Alguém sabe de algum jeito de criptografar algum dado, *two-handle*, de modo que posso descriptografar?
Eu adorei o MD5 e o jeito que ele fixa o comprimento do *hash*, o problema é que não há como descriptografar (unidirecional/*one-handle*).

**base64 é ruim para mim** porquê ele geralmente aumenta o tamanho do que já escrevi, 30% maior (como descrito no manual), e na verdade a intenção da criptografia é diminuir...

O texto a ser criptografado deve variar de 10~100 caracteres, alfa-numerico, e o campo onde desejo armazenar a criptografia não vai aceitar mais que 32.

Comment: Tem como detalhar um bocadinho mais ?

Comment: `base64` não é algoritmo de criptografia. Tem certeza que o que você deseja não é um algoritmo de compressão? Inteção da criptografia não é diminuir dado, e sim ocultar dado. Quem diminui o tamanho do dado é a compressão. Colocar algo do tamanho de 100 caracteres em um campo que aceite apenas 32 vai ser bem complicado, a não ser que seu dado tenha características muito específicas que permitem grande compressão. E ainda assim, desconheço algoritmos que trabalhem com tão pouco overhead. Detalhe mais o seu problema.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira , então base64 é de codificação ao invés de criptografia? Confundi os conceitos.. sim, de compressão talvez me ajude, a ideia é que ocupe até 32 caracteres um texto que pode variar de 10~100. Fica ruim de explicar porquê preciso fazer isso, mas realmente precisa ser desta maneira. Vi algo com gzcompress, mas parece que os caracteres ficam bugados, será que isso pode atrapalhar na hora de salvar no banco de dados?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você busca não é criptografia (técnica para ocultar dados) e sim compressão (técnica para armazenar dados usando uma quantidade menor de bits que em seu formato "cru"). base64 não é nem um nem outro (é apenas uma forma de serialização - codificar um dado binário arbitrário em um conjunto de 64 caracteres).

Para representar um dado de até 100 caracteres num campo de 32 você enfrenta uma série de problemas:

- Nenhum algoritmo de compressão sem perdas possui desempenho positivo no pior caso ([princípio da casa dos pombos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_casa_dos_pombos)). Isso significa que existe um limite inferior para o espaço que esses 100 caracteres alfanuméricos ocuparão, que é o seguinte:

  - 7 bits para armazenar o tamanho da sequência (|10-100| = 90 < 128) +
  - Sem nenhum [alinhamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment):

    - 517 bits para `[a-z0-9]` (log<sub>2</sub>36<sup>100</sup>)
    - 596 bits para `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (log<sub>2</sub>62<sup>100</sup>)
    - 676 bits se considerarmos os acentos em todas as variações usadas na língua portuguesa.
  - Com alinhamento de caractere pra caractere

    - 600 bits para `[a-z0-9]` ou `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (100*6)
    - 700 bits se considerarmos também os acentos.

  Como você pode ver, mesmo no caso mais simples são necessários ao menos 66 bytes pra representar *todas* as sequências alfanuméricas de tamanho até 100. A menos que exista alguma peculiaridade nos seus dados (digamos, as sequências possíveis sejam apenas um subconjunto do total, digamos só aquelas que formam palavras, etc) você não conseguirá um meio de comprimir sem perdas todas essas sequências.
- Mesmo que você conseguisse "espremer" seu dado em 32 bytes, se o campo é do tipo "texto" (i.e. guarda até 32 **caracteres**) ele não vai necessariamente aceitar todos os valores possíveis por "caractere":

  - Se o campo tiver codificação UTF-8, cada caractere pode ocupar mais de um byte (até 5 ou 6 se não me engano). Dependendo da forma de compressão você pode tornar seu dado *maior* em vez de menor...
  - Se o campo tiver codificação UTF-16 (improvável), nem todo par de bytes pode ocorrer em isolamento - alguns são [*surrogate pairs*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Pontos_de_c.C3.B3digo_U.2BD800_a_U.2BDFFF), que precisam ocorrer juntos (complicando a codificação).
  - Se o campo tiver codificação UTF-32 (ainda mais improvável), então você está com sorte: há ao menos 19 bits disponíveis em cada caractere, para um total de 608 (ainda insuficiente pro caso dos dados acentuados, mas suficiente pros demais).

  Agora se o limite de tamanho do campo estiver expresso em bytes mesmo, aí é inútil (máximo de 256 bits, bem menor que os 524 que você precisa no mínimo).
- Converter de e para esse formato "otimizado" vai dar trabalho, não apenas do ponto de vista de codificar uma solução (ou achar uma já pronta) como também no tempo que seu script PHP vai demorar para fazer o processo de conversão.

Concluindo, não há nada que se possa fazer no caso geral. Em casos específicos, por outro lado, pode ser que haja uma solução. No exemplo que eu dei das palavras, a frequência de cada letra é diferente, então normalmente dá pra comprimir um bocado com a [codificação de Huffman](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Huffman). Mas mesmo assim nada é garantido (sempre podem existir palavras que ficarão maiores que os 32 caracteres desejados, caso suas letras não obedeçam à frequência típica do idioma em questão).

Comment: Ótimo, show de resposta,.. Parabéns! Acho que vou me contentar em resolver por outra forma, ao invés de comprimir.